# Selenium: PhantomJS slower than Firefox

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, urllib2

I wrote Selenium test that clicks through my ExtJS-Twisted web application and works very slow.

Could someone explain why PhantomJS runs a lot slower than Firefox on my configuration? What's wrong with urllib2's method *recv*?

#### Profiler statistics:

- PhantomJS

  ```
  Ran 1 test in 137.150s

  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  4485    124.000  0.028    124.000    0.028 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
  ```
- Firefox

  ```
  Ran 1 test in 36.660s

  ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  96910   23.061   0.000    23.061     0.000 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
  ```

#### Network statistics:

```
[tester@server ~]$ tracepath 192.168.200.65
 1:  192.168.200.77 (192.168.200.77)                        0.207ms pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.200.65 (192.168.200.65)                        0.773ms reached
 1:  192.168.200.65 (192.168.200.65)                        0.351ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 64 
[tester@server ~]$ tracepath 192.168.200.83
 1:  192.168.200.77 (192.168.200.77)                        0.087ms pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.200.83 (192.168.200.83)                        0.733ms reached
 1:  192.168.200.83 (192.168.200.83)                        0.654ms reached
     Resume: pmtu 1500 hops 1 back 64
```

#### Test machines:

- 77-th runs web application
- 65-th runs `Docker` with `PhantomJS` (reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618113/selenium-webdriver-socket-error-connection-reset-by-peer-for-non-root-users)
- 83-th runs local `Firefox` or `PhantomJS` from 65-th against web application on 77-th with.